# How to reference an event in C#

Tags: c#, events, reference, callback, event-handling

I have the following class, which has one public event called `LengthChanged`:

```
class Dimension
{
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.length;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.length != value)
            {
                this.length = value;
                this.OnLengthChanged ();
            }
    }

    protected virtual void OnLengthChanged()
    {
        var handler = this.LengthChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler (this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event System.EventHandler LengthChanged;

    private int length;
}
```

I would like to be able to register/unregister handlers for this event in a method called `Observer`, which does not know anything about the `Dimension` class. I have come up with two scenarios, none of which are really satisfying:

1. Define an interface `ILengthChanged` with the `LengthChanged` event, then make sure `Dimension` implements `ILengthChanged`. Then I have to provide one implementation of the `Observer` method for every interface I define. This by no way generic enough. I'd really want to be able to simply pass in a reference to a `System.EventHandler` event.
2. Use `System.Action<System.EventHandler>` callbacks for registering and unregistering the event handler in the `Observer` method, just like that:

```cs
    class Foo
    {
        public void Observer(System.Action<System.EventHandler> register,
                             System.Action<System.EventHandler> unregister)
        {
            register (this.MyEventHandler);

            // keep track of the unregister callback, so that we can unregister
            // our event handler later on, if needed...
        }

        private void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

which would then be invoked like this:

```
Foo foo = ...;
Dimension dim = ...;

foo.Observer (x => dim.LengthChanged += x, x => dim.LengthChanged -= x);
```

and which, when executed, will indeed end up wiring the `LengthChanged` event with the internal event handler `MyEventHandler`. But this is not very elegant. I would have loved to be able to write this instead:

```
Foo foo = ...;
Dimension dim = ...;

foo.Observer (dim.LengthChanged);
```

but I've no idea how this could be achieved. Maybe I am missing something really obvious here? I guess that some `dynamic` magic could do the trick, somehow, but this would not enforce compile-time type checking: I don't want the users of `Observer` to pass in references to events which do not satisfy the `System.EventHandler` event signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't really a way of doing this. Events aren't first class citizens in .NET in general - although F# tries to promote them there.

Either pass in the subscribe/unsubscribe delegate or using a string indicating the name of the event. (The latter is often shorter, but obviously less safe at compile-time.)

Those are the approaches which [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) takes - if there were a cleaner way of doing it, I'm sure they would be using that :(

Comment: If people like Erik Meijer were not able to come up with cleaner solutions, I suspect that indeed, there is no other way to do it. That's sad... Thank you for your quick reply, Jon.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom accessor.

```
public event EventHandler NewEvent
{
    add { Dimension.LengthChanged += value; }
    remove { Dimension.LengthChanged -= value; }
}
```

Please [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors).

Answer (score 2):

Event is not supposed to be passed into another method.  However, you can pass delegate into another method.  Perhaps, what you are looking for are just a simple public delegate instead of event.

If you change your event to this

```
public System.EventHandler LengthChanged;
```

You can simply pass the LengthChanged to Observer like this

```
Foo foo = ...;
Dimension dim = ...;
foo.Observer (dim.LengthChanged);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. No, I cannot pass the delegate instead of the event; the event might implement the `add` and `remove` setters and really has to be defined as a full fledged C# `event`.

Comment: @Pierre I see.. in that case, what I would do is to declare a delegate wrapper class.  The constructor of that class takes a delegate.  The class has virtual AddHandler() and virtual RemoveHandler().  It also has a Invoke() method to call the delegate.  To make it look more elegant, you can define operator +=, -=, + and -, calling your AddHandler and RemoveHandler.  Replace your Dimension's LengthChanged event by this wrapper class.  For the case you need "add" and "remove" setters, just override that wrapper class's AddHandler and RemoveHandler methods.  Just my 2 cents.  I have done similar.

Comment: nice solution... I'll have to think it over. +1 for this nice hack.